# Show/Hide Toggle for a Toggle

Tags: usability, design-patterns, toggle, options, modal

We have a toggle available in our main screen, to enable/disable an important functionality. Since, only 30% of our users use this functionality at least once per month, we are considering to (optionally) move the functionality toggle from the main screen to the settings, to make it less intrusive and less prominent to our 70% of our users.

We believe it should be optional, so that we allow the 30% of our users to keep it available in the main screen.

**Our problem is the following:**

User can enable/disable the functionality either from within the main screen or from the settings, however, he is allowed to show/hide the toggle from the main screen, if he finds it less useful.

*Technically, we want to introduce a "show/hide" toggle, for a toggle...*

How can we communicate this, without impacting the cognitive load of our users?

[image]

Comment: Is "sport mode" something that might need to be accessed urgently? Would putting it in Settings become an obstacle for users who need it right away?

Comment: Yes, for this 30% who use it, it s something they use “urgently” and they consider highly important for us to hide it inside settings

Comment: Would it be better for them if they had a toggle on the home screen to save time, but if everyone else saw it in Settings?

Answer (score 3):

The concern is that the user might not understand the difference between the two options in the settings.

I think the simple solution is that you can just use a more descriptive explanation for the option that is used to toggle the toggle. For example:

> Allow "Sport Mode" to be toggled from the main page.

You could even opt to make this a simple checkbox setting to help further distinguish the two settings.

Something like this:

[image]